# Remove unsupported grant types from discovery document [IS4]

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

We are doing some due diligence on our OAuth (Identity Server 4 based) server and I noticed something weird. We have several clients setup and they all use either Authorization flow or Device flow, some use offline access (refresh tokens) and nothing else. Yet the discovery document lists additional grant types:

```json
"grant_types_supported": [
    "authorization_code",
    "client_credentials",
    "refresh_token",
    "implicit",
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
],
```

I know that IS4 will not allow implicit flow if client itself does not allow it, but for cleanliness and correctness, and if possible, I would like to only list grant types which are actually supported. I am not even sure where the `implicit` and `client_credentials` came from, nor can I seem to find anything related to this in `IdentityServerOptions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not edit the default types because they are hard-coded in [DiscoveryResponseGenerator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/5bcc2abbcf6c47200c4eb3b77e756f1bc0e04358/src/IdentityServer4/src/ResponseHandling/Default/DiscoveryResponseGenerator.cs#L254).

But you can implement your own [IDiscoveryResponseGenerator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/ResponseHandling/IDiscoveryResponseGenerator.cs) and replace it in DI.

Another options is to hide all grant types from discovery document.
Use `Discovery.ShowGrantTypes` property of `IdentityServerOptions` class.